# Scroll Snap detect OnExit of Section

Tags: reactjs, scroll, css-animations

In my Home I have 2 sections, and I am using scroll snap in y direction. Now I want that on scroll in downwards 'y', my IconContainer component in section A should move to bottom of the section A and then the scroll should happen.

```
import {
    StyledContainer,
    NameHeading,
    Location,
    Description,
    Wrapper,
} from './Styles/SectionAStyles';
import IconContainer from '../../ui/IconContainer/IconContainer';
import { LocationPin } from '../../utilities/icons';
import { IconProvider } from '../../ui/IconProvider/IconProvider';
import SectionABackgroundElement from './Components/DesignBlock/SectionABackgroundElement';

export default function SectionA() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <SectionABackgroundElement />
            <StyledContainer>
                <NameHeading>
                    <div>Hi, I'm</div>
                    <IconContainer
                        Image={'kanav-pic.jpeg'}
                        size={3}
                        hasMargin={false}
                    />
                    <div>Kanav</div>
                </NameHeading>
                <Location>
                    <IconProvider Icon={LocationPin} size={1} />
                    <div>Delhi, India</div>
                </Location>
                <Description>
                    I'm currently at Deloitte, I have been working as Open
                    Source Contributor and Freelancer
                </Description>
            </StyledContainer>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

I tried framer motion for that but framer motion is working when I remove scroll snap as with scroll snap whole section becomes one scroll. But I want scroll snap. I just want that this animation should work as I am using same image as section B background that's why I want this smooth transition